# Preventing SQL injections in CakePHP3 full text index match

Tags: mysql, cakephp, full-text-search, sql-injection, cakephp-3.x

I need to do a fulltext search on a table in CakePHP3. I do the search like this:

```
$ids = $this->I18n->find('list', [
    'valueField' => 'foreign_key',
    'conditions' => [
        'field IN' => ['name', 'description_search', 'description_short_search'],
        'model' => 'Products',
        'locale' => $lang,
        'MATCH (content) AGAINST ("'.$filteredValue.'")',
    ],
])->toArray();
```

This works, but is unsafe - this is a perfect place for an SQL injection. I tried replacing it with a parameter (`MATCH (content) AGAINST (?)' => $filteredValue`), but that generates an error `Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters`.

How can I safeguard against this?

(Yes, this is a match against the standard i18n table. A bit of a hack, but irrelevant to the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using bindings

That's not how bindings work anymore, in CakePHP 3.x you have to use the `Query::bind()` method (or `StatementInterface::bindValue()` when using custom statements).

```
$ids = $this->I18n
    ->find('list', [
        'valueField' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => [
            'field IN' => ['name', 'description_search', 'description_short_search'],
            'model' => 'Products',
            'locale' => $lang,
            'MATCH (content) AGAINST (:against)',
        ],
    ])
    ->bind(':against', $filteredValue, 'string')
    ->toArray();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > SQL Injection Prevention > Binding Values](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#binding-values)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::bind()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_bind)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Binding Values](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#binding-values)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\StatementInterface::bindValue()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.StatementInterface.html#_bindValue)**